# Finitism and $\exists$- Introduction Rule.

Tags: logic, philosophy

Does finitism allow $\exists$- Introduction Rule which says that if $x$ is not free in $\psi$, infer $\exists x\phi\rightarrow\psi$ from $\phi\rightarrow\psi$?

As far as I know, finitist would not accept quantification over infinite domains. If finitist accept $\exists$-Introduction Rule, then what does the rule mean for finitist?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the connection ? At most, we may say that finitism accept only *finite* universe. The above rule is *valid*, i.e. true in every interpretation: if there are only interpretation with finite domain... what changes ?

Comment: @Mauro: Thank you. Can I give you one more question? I don't know why there is a finitist who believes  in Primitive Recursive Arithmetic but doen not believe in Peano Arithmetic. Is there any differences between them which is at issue for finitist?

Comment: You can see [William Tait's papers](http://home.uchicago.edu/~wwtx/)